# Flutter - Disable Scrolling in GridView until childs fill the height

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview, scroll

I'm kinda confused.

What I try to do is to have a GridView with some elements. In my initial state, I have an add button. The add button adds elements to the grid view.

The GridView should only scroll if the screen is filled with elements but it's already scrollable in my initial state.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @Julián Found the solution, needed to set the physics to BouncingScrollPhysics

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!!

You need to set the physics to:

**BouncingScrollPhysics**, **RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics**, **ClampingScrollPhysics**(removes the bounce effect you normally have on scrolling to end or beginning), or **PageScrollPhysics**.

I recommend **BouncingScrollPhysics** or **RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics**.

Code Example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              _buildHeading(),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1 / 20,
              ),
              _renderImage(),
              _buildSubtitle(),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2 / 20,
              ),
              _buildUsernameInput()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Also works on **GridView**, **ListView** etc.